# Lua string match/find

Tags: string, lua

I am trying to capture undesirable usernames in our game server using the code below. Currently, it will let anyone pass regardless of their username. I have had it working were it stops connections to the server with individual words, but so far I'm struggling with picking up banned words in strings.

```
local unauthNames = { "admin", "word1", "etc" }

for name in pairs(unauthNames) do
    if string.find(string.lower(GetPlayerName(source)), unauthNames[name]) then
        print(playerName .. " has been kicked for having an unauthorised name")
        setKickReason("Your name is not permitted. Please check your name is not offensive or associated with blacklisted organisations.")
        CancelEvent()
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: Don't. Blacklisting words in usernames is a very bad idea for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Also, your if-condition would look much nicer as `if GetPlayerName(source):lower():find(forbidden) then`

Comment: What does `unauthNames` look like? is it a sequence? It would help having a bit more context for what your code exactly does.

Comment: Apologies unauthNames is a list of variables

local unauthNames = {
    "admin",
    "word1",
    "etc"
}

Answer (score 0):

```
AddEventHandler("playerConnecting", function(playerName, setKickReason)
    playerName = string.gsub(playerName, "%W", ""):lower()
    for k, v in pairs(unauthNames) do
      local g, f = playerName:find(string.lower(v)
      if g or f then
          print(playerName .. " has been kicked for having an unauthorised name")
          setKickReason("Your name is not permitted. Please check your name is not offensive or associated with blacklisted organisations.")
          CancelEvent()
      end
    end
  end)
```

Comment: That `string.gsub` returns the first alphanumeric character in the username and you're missing a `)`. That code couldn't possibly work.

Answer (score -1):

```
AddEventHandler("playerConnecting", function(playerName, setKickReason)
    playerName = (string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(string.gsub(playerName,  "-", ""), ",", ""), "%.", ""), " ", ""):lower())
    for k, v in pairs(unauthNames) do
      local g, f = playerName:find(string.lower(v))
      if g or f then
        local id = source;
        local ids = ExtractIdentifiers(id);
        local ip = ids.ip;
        local steam = ids.steam:gsub("steam:", "");
        local steamDec = tostring(tonumber(steam,16));
        steam = "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" .. steamDec;
        local gameLicense = ids.license;
        local discord = ids.discord;
        local realName = GetPlayerName(source);
          print(playerName .. " has been kicked for having an unauthorised name")
          sendToDisc("Anti-abuse - Player kicked for having an unauthorised name",
          'Steam: **' .. steam .. '**\n' ..
          'GameLicense: **' .. gameLicense .. '**\n' ..
          'Discord UID: **' .. discord:gsub('discord:', '') .. '**\n'
          .. 'Name: **' .. realName ..'**\n'
          .. 'Blacklisted Item: **' .. v ..'**\n');
          setKickReason("[Anti-abuse] Your name, or part of it, is not permitted. Please check your name is not offensive, does not contain weblinks, odd characters or other restricted content: " ..v)
          CancelEvent()
      end
    end
  end)
```

Here is the deployed version with discord integration.